# Сложно ли написать бота для ставок в букмекерской конторе?

Tags: java, парсер, бот

Хочу сделать бота, который будет по простому алгоритму делать 20-30 ставок в сутки в лайве. Чтобы для конторы он был неотличим от реального пользователя. Я так понял что в лайве коэффициенты изменяются 1 раз в секунду с помощью ajax. Также иногда при авторизации требуется ввод капчи, но сессия после этого длится примерно сутки при поддержании минимальной активности. Может посоветуете какую-нибудь библиотеку или еще что? До этого ajax не парсил, а только статические страницы. Мне в java библиотеки JSoup хватало

Comment: AJAX запрос по своей сути ничем не отличается от статической страницы. Немного заголовки другие. Откройте в хроме этот сайт + панель разработчика, вкладка сеть. XHR и есть AJAX. Можно выделить запрос и выбрать "Copy as curl". Будут скопированы все заголовки. Это можно вставить "как есть" в консоль и запустить. Ну потом под Java перетащить. Еще save as HAR посмотри, там в JSON все как на ладони

Answer (score 2):

Используй Selenium Webdriver, будешь через реальный браузер работать:

**Преимущества:**

- Обработка Javascript
- Можно ожидать подгрузки контента Ajax
- Большое количество браузеров
- Имитация действий пользователя
- Большое количество языков программирования (знаю точно: Java, Python, C#)

**Недостатки:**

- Медленнее
- Требует webdriver к браузерам

Comment: Для данной задачи нужна скорость, эмуляция полноценного браузера не подходит.

Comment: @LeonidMew ну тогда только парсить постоянно AJAX - запросы

Comment: Прочел что селениум запускается за 10 секунд. Он сможет поддерживать соединение со страницей или его нужно будет перезапускать для получения свежих данных? У меня ставки будут на 1 спорт, на одной странице